# Copy Java installation to another system

Tags: windows, windows-registry, java, path

I'd like to create a detached/offline Java setup on Windows to roll out to other systems and VMs. I know that some applications bundle Java within them, but I was wondering if I can also create a Java installation that I can port to another system. i.e. I don't want to install Java from the Oracle installer, or from chocolatey or other package managers. I want to get a vanilla Java setup folder from one system, and then port to another system or VM, and ideally into a different folder from the default (`C:\MyApps\Java`).

The main obvious considerations are PATH and registry. Certainly, I would add the folder containing `java.exe` etc to the PATH. Would that be sufficient? Would a `.jar` file then use those binaries, or would I further need to add registry information as well as the PATH?

How would we create a completely portable version of Java in this way?

Comment: As you can see on Oracle OTN site you have archive with java files: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk19-windows (x64 Compressed Archive)

Comment: Also https://adoptium.net/temurin/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/download

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start, but there is literally no explanation of how to make it usable to .jar files etc. I looked at the below link and it only talks about the .exe install. Do we just put java.exe / javaw.exe on the PATH and that's that? Java very often feels obscurantist I've noticed. Do you know how I *use* the .zip archive such that java apps can see/manipulate it? https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/install/installation-jdk-microsoft-windows-platforms.html#GUID-DED545A1-ED43-4821-B25A-736214617690

Comment: I don't even particularly need the JDK (I think). I just want Java support on the system (so that would be the JRE I think). I only develop in PowerShell, Python, Bash, C#, so probably the JDK might be too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How would we create a completely portable version of Java in this way?

You can do this with a `cmd` script:

1. Copy the complete Java installation to the new system.
2. Set `JAVA_HOME` to point to the root directory of your Java installation, for example:

   ```
    setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_231"
   ```
3. Add the Java bin directory to your path, for example:

   ```
    setx PATH "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin";%PATH%
   ```

See [Installing the JDK Software](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html#CHDEBCCJ) and [Setting JAVA_HOME and PATH and CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks David. If it all comes down to just `JAVA_HOME` and updating the the `PATH`, then that's great to know (I was hoping it was something as simple as this). I note the difference in paths; `JAVA_HOME` to the root of the `jre` and `PATH` to the `bin` folder. I'll convert this to PowerShell, and it should be perfect for my needs. Thanks for the tip.