# PowerShell, properly association .jar files with java.exe or javaw.exe

Tags: powershell, windows-registry, java, file-association

Using the answer from this question [Copy Java installation to another system](https://superuser.com/questions/1756084/copy-java-installation-to-another-system) I can manually install Java (without running the installer) and port it to other systems. This works well.

However, I still cannot get java .jar files to properly associate with `java.exe` or `javaw.exe`. I am using the following to create the association (I created this by taking a registry snapshot to see what keys were changed during the association - when I double-click on a `.jar` and point it to `java.exe`, but this fails to create the association. I have routinely done things like this before to associate things, but here it fails completely, so I would appreciate if anyone can tell me how to get `.jar` apps properly associated so that they will open when I double click on tha `.jar` (note that I tried the below to associate with `java.exe` and with `javaw.exe`. Both failed unfortunately.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.jar]
@="jar_auto_file"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\java.exe]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\java.exe\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\java.exe\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\java.exe\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\WDAGUtilityAccount\\Desktop\\MySandbox\\MyPrograms\\java\\bin\\java.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\jar_auto_file]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\jar_auto_file\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\jar_auto_file\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\jar_auto_file\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\WDAGUtilityAccount\\Desktop\\MySandbox\\MyPrograms\\java\\bin\\java.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jar\OpenWithList]
"MRUList"="ba"
"b"="java.exe"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jar\OpenWithProgids]
"jar_auto_file"=hex(0):

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jar\UserChoice]
"ProgId"="Applications\\java.exe"
"Hash"="jHq42dyBKxc="

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
"GlobalAssocChangedCounter"=dword:00000003
```

Comment: Does [How to Fix .JAR (Executable Jar File) File Association in Windows » Winhelponline](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/repair-jar-file-association-windows/) answer your question?

Comment: This works really well for me, thanks. I used the `jarfix` tool mentioned there, which I can automate the download of via `choco install jarfix -y` and then I used only the `/s` switch (for silent). Presumably it is finding my Java installation in the non-standard location via my `JAVA_HOME` envinronment variable, and from that it properly updated the associations and all .jar files are opening correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I get `.jar` associated so they will open when double clicked?

The easiest solution is to use the Jarfix utility:

> If you double-click on a jar file, and your Java application does not
> start, your .jar association has been hijacked. You can fix the
> problem with Jarfix:
>
> Download Jarfix:
>
> https://johann.loefflmann.net/en/software/jarfix/index.html#Download
>
> This little portable app automatically finds the `Javaw.exe` location
> (by finding the current Java version and Java Home path from the
> registry) and fixes the `.JAR` file association settings in the
> registry.
>
> [image]

Source: [How to Fix .JAR (Executable Jar File) File Association in Windows » Winhelponline](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/repair-jar-file-association-windows/#jarfix)

Comment: I see also that the switches are listed on the authors website. I used "/s" to make `jarfix` run silently. https://johann.loefflmann.net/en/software/jarfix/index.html